# Какие реальные проекты можно делать для практики на React?

Tags: reactjs

начал изучать React, есть желание попробовать свои силы на практике. Разные To do листа, добавление элемента и.т.п я уже изучил. Какие есть примеры реальных задач который действительно нужны в коммерческой части разработке. Смотрел на фрилансе но там вакансии лишь, детальное ТЗ дают лишь исполнителям, поэтому решил спросить у добрый друзей на stack overflow

Comment: Сделайте Facebook

Comment: Не хочу отбирать хлеб у Цукерберга

Comment: сделайте виджет, который позволяет пользователю нарисовать блок-схему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте выполнить тестовое задание в любую компанию. Они чаще всего бывают очень приближенными к бизнем-задачам, которые решают в этих компаниях. Кроме того, бонусом вам будет возможность устроиться в эту компанию или другую, в любом случае опыт пригодится. Вот одно из заданий:

```
Реализовать приложение, которое умеет показывать следующие страницы:

/ - главная
/login - страница ввода логина и пароля
/news - страница с новостями (любая однотипная информация)
/profile - страница с произвольным текстом, недоступная без авторизации
На сайте, в шапке или подвале реализовать ссылки:

На главную (/)
Новости (/news)
Профиль (/profile)
Если пользователь кликает на страницу “профиля” и он не “авторизован” - перекидывать на страницу /login

Форма входа (/login) принимает “фейковые” данные:

username: Admin
password: 12345 
Если введены другие данные, то показывается сообщения:

Имя пользователя или пароль введены не верно 
Если введены корректные данные, то перебрасывать на страницу /profile

Информацию об авторизации пользователя можно хранить в localStorage, простым параметром true/false. Базу данных реализовать не нужно.

Запрос за новостями, попытку залогиниться и все что посчитаете нужным - пробросить через Redux.
```

Ссылка на [источник](https://hackmd.io/@b1hdcBB2Qmu9KtH_ycT20Q/BJWYLsmD4?type=view).

Ещё куча тестовых заданий в ведущие компании [вот здесь](https://github.com/Hexlet/ru-test-assignments).

Comment: Спасибо большое)